# Laravel Modal keeps on deleting the last id in the database

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi Im trying to make a delete confirmation using modal in laravel in my users table.
I noticed that the delete button is working but the delete button always deletes the last entry in the table and in the confirmation I put some `<p>Are you sure you want to delete {{$row->name}}</p>`  but the name there is always from the last entry. here is my whole modal code

```
<!-- Delete Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="userDelete"  tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete User</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Are you sure you want to delete {{$row->name}}</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         {!!Form::open(['action' => ['UserController@destroy', $row->id], 'method' => 'POST','class'=>'pull-right'])!!}
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          {{Form::submit('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])}}
          {{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
          {!!Form::close()!!}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is my controller code for destroy

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $users = User::find($id);
        if(auth()->user()->userType =="admin")
        {   
           
            $users->delete();
        }
        else
        {
        return redirect('/users')->with('error', 'Admin is only authorized to delete users');
        }
        
        return redirect('/users')->with('success', 'User Removed!');
    }
```

and here is my table body code

```
@foreach ($users as $row)
     <tbody id="myTable">
         <tr>
             <td>{{$row->id}}</td>
             <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
             <td>{{$row->email}}</td>
             <td>{{$row->created_at}}</td>
             <td>{{$row->userType}}</td>
             <td><a href="" class="btn btn-success">Validate</a>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data- 
            target="#userDelete">Delete</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
@endforeach
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please show the controller code.

Comment: I show the controller code.

Comment: Where's the loop that your modal in?. If the modal code isn't in a loop so it takes the last user id from from other loop and put it in the modal.

Comment: what kind of loop should I put?

Comment: Where and how do u include the modal in your blade file? How do you pass the id in your modal?

Comment: The same loop you used to display the user data.

Comment: Your modal is at the bottom of the page (I think). When you have finished displaying your table, $row will be the data from the last row. So the modal will have show the last row. what ever you click on. You need to pass data to the modal, so that when you click on it, you know which row you've clicked. At the moment it has no idea which row you've clicked.

Answer (score 5):

Your modal always getting the last `id` because,

- in each button click, it is always detecting same modal, which takes the last row id.
- You need to define separate modal for each data, just like you define separate row in table for each data entry.
- Then in each button click, detect corresponding modal to delete.

Reformat your code like following.

In table body code: update button data-target

```
@foreach ($users as $row)
     <tbody id="myTable">
         <tr>
             <td>{{$row->id}}</td>
             ...
             <td><a href="" class="btn btn-success">Validate</a>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" 
                      data-target="#userDelete_{{$row->id}}">
                         Delete
                </button>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
@endforeach
```

The above  `data-target="#userDelete_{{$row->id}}"`, will now identify different modal id such as, `userDelete_1`, `userDelete_2` etc. based on button click

Now write the modal code inside `foreach` loop after the table, like following:

```
@foreach ($users as $row)
     <tbody id="myTable>
        ...
    </tbody>

<!-- Delete Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="userDelete_{{$row->id}}"  tabindex="-1"
       arialabelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete User</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Are you sure you want to delete {{$row->name}}</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         {!!Form::open(['action' => ['UserController@destroy', $row->id], 'method' => 'POST','class'=>'pull-right'])!!}
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          {{Form::submit('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])}}
          {{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
          {!!Form::close()!!}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Now, if your route path and form is okay, i think your problem will be solved.

Comment: Perfect! This worked for me.